# What Linux utility enables knowing devise is running or shut?

Tags: hardware, devices, monitoring

I'm seeking any solution to detect hardware instances which are in or out of operation (till restart) in Linux distro like Ubuntu 18.04. Essentially, what terminal-built or loadable utility serves to find out the operation status of devices like keyboard, mouse etc.? I wonder if Linux has some built-in monitor program which function is the same or similar to what I'm looking for.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1232450/edit) your question and add specific information regarding which devices you want to find out. Are these external devices? Are they all connected by USB? Are they connected by some other interfaces, such as Thunderbolt, Ethernet port, HDMI? Are these devices connected internally by PCIe socket, M.2 socket, SATA, PATA, or some other means? This is a question answer site. Please visit site [help](https://askubuntu.com/help) to understand how to ask specific questions appropriate for this site.

Comment: The Linux kernel handles hardware interaction. It makes root and/or userspace access to hardware available through /dev. Under most circumstances, if hardware is detected is should be available for use. Hardware out-of-operation would generally be considered a bug.